# Puppet: Could not request certificate

Tags: puppet

When i start puppet agent i get this error

```
Could not request certificate: Could not intern from text/plain: Certname "puppet ca: localhost/localdomain" must not contain unprintable or non-ASCII characters
```

Both puppet master and agent version are 3.8.7

In both master and agent /etc/hosts file i added these lines:

```
10.11.22.166 pclient
10.11.22.173 pmaster
```

I can ping both pclient and pmaster from each other.

In puppet master puppet.conf i added this line:

```
[master]
certname = pmaster
```

In puppet agent puppet.conf file i added this line in [main] block:

```
server = pmaster
```

Enabled 8140 port:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8140 -j ACCEPT
```

Please help me, I don't know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: This is not about connectivity the issue appears to be with your certificate. 

Have you actually created this certificate? 
`[master]
certname = pmaster`

it doesn't like the **/** in `localhost/localdomain`

If this is cert created by you in openssl then try to to change it. 

Alternatively generate cert using puppet and then copy it to all of you nodes 
`puppet cert —generate <cert name>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your hostname not right.
delete the ssl dir(/var/lib/puppet/ssl) and resign again

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run some of your files through `cat -v` and see if they contain any unprintable characters.

Comment: This is good advice, but not an answer to the question.  It is better suited for a comment.